# Docker image for built Golang binary

Tags: docker, go

I have a Go application that I build into a binary and distribute as a Docker image.

Currently, I'm using `ubuntu` as my base image, but this causes an issue where if a user tries to use a Timezone other than UTC or their local timezone, they get an error stating:

```
pod error: panic: open /usr/local/go/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip: no such file or directory
```

This error is caused because the [LoadLocation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation) package in Go requires that file.

I can think of two ways to fix this issue:

1. Continue using the `ubuntu` base image, but in my Dockerfile add the commands: `RUN apt-get install -y tzdata`
2. Use one of Golang's base images, eg. `golang:1.7.5-alpine`.

What would be the recommended way? I'm not sure if I need to or should be using a Golang image since this is the container where the pre-built binary runs. My understanding is that Golang images are good for building the binary in the first place.

Comment: If you need the `tzdata` package, then you need to install that. What image are you building your binary with?

Comment: I currently do not build within a container. I do intend to fix that by building using the `golang:1.7.5-alpine` container

Comment: If you not building with alpine, you need to be sure you're building a static binary if you intend to release with alpine. Either way you need the zoneinfo in your final container if you're using it in your program.

Comment: @JimB I am currently building a static binary targeted for my current runtime container. Regarding zoneinfo, I'm trying to figure out the best way to have that in my final container - should I install the `tzdata` package in my `ubuntu` container, or use one of `golang` containers.

Comment: That's entirely up to you. You can view the associated Dockerfiles, and see if one suits your needs more than the other. There is no "right" answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a vote, but apt-get is what we (my company's tech group) do in situations like this. It gives us complete control over the hierarchy of images, but this is assuming you may have future images based on this one.

Comment: Thanks. Marking this as accepted since this is the approach I ended up going with.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use multi-stage build. On 1st step you use special golang building container for installing all dependencies and build an application. On 2nd stage I copy binary file to empty `alpine` container. This allows having all required tooling and minimal docker image simultaneously (in my case 6MB instead of 280MB).

Example of `Dockerfile`:

```
# build stage
FROM golang:1.8
ADD . /src
RUN set -x && \
    cd /src && \
    go get -t -v github.com/lisitsky/go-site-search-string && \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -o goapp

# final stage
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /src/goapp /app/
ENTRYPOINT /goapp
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: With this approach, your final runtime container won't have the time data at `/usr/local/go/lib/time/` though

Comment: @xbonez of couse, if you need some data files what aren't get compiled into binary you can `ADD` them. This way you get minimal image - only things you need.

Answer (score 2):

Since not all OS have localized timezone installed, this is what I did to make it work:

```
ADD https://github.com/golang/go/raw/master/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip /usr/local/go/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip
```

The full example of multi-step Docker image for adding timezone is [here](https://gist.github.com/tsuz/08f84647eea856bc1e2f136130955579)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the system's tzdata. Or you can copy `$GOROOT/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip` into your image, which is a trimmed version of the system one.